# How do I do mulitple joins on two databases tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

The goal is to join all the same values (the duplicates) together. Email, timestamp and daystamp.

I have created one join statement

```sql
SELECT history.email, history.timestamp, payment.timestamp, 
       history.daystamp, payment.daystamp
FROM history
FULL OUTER JOIN payment ON history.email = payment.email
ORDER BY history.email;
```

I have all the unique email addresses. How do I do the same for the timestamp and daystamp?

Can I do three outer joins in one statement?

Comment: Can you describe your all the tables being used in the query. Sample Dataset for your table and what output you are expecting

Comment: Goal is unclear. `on history.email = payment.email or history.daystamp = payment.daystamp and history.timestamp = payment.timestamp`?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods that might be useful to adapt to your specific problem here although it's a little unclear without sample data.

Method 1:

```sql
SELECT  A.column2
        , B.column2
        , C.column2
FROM 
(
    (SELECT month, column2 FROM table1) A
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT month, column2 FROM table2) B on A.month= B.month
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT month, column2 FROM table3) C on A.month= C.month
)
```

Method 2:

```
select
    A.column2,
    B.column2,
    C.column2
from (
    select distinct month from table1
    union
    select distinct month from table2
    union
    select distinct month from table3
) as X
    left outer join table1 as A on A.month = X.month
    left outer join table2 as B on B.month = X.month
    left outer join table3 as C on C.month = X.month
```

Comment: The unions will actually take care of distinctness.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

> ```
> SELECT 
>   case when p.payment_id is not null then 'p' else 'h' end as tbl
> , coalesce(h.email, p.email) as email
> , coalesce(h.timestamp, p.timestamp) as timestamp
> , coalesce(h.daystamp, p.daystamp) as daystamp
> FROM history h
> FULL JOIN payment p
>   ON h.email = p.email 
>  AND h.timestamp = p.timestamp 
>  AND h.daystamp is not distinct from p.daystamp 
> WHERE (h.history_id is null or p.payment_id is null) 
> ORDER BY coalesce(h.email, p.email);
> ```
>
> ```
> tbl | email          | timestamp           | daystamp
> :-- | :------------- | :------------------ | -------:
> h   | test2@mail.not | 2022-02-22 22:22:22 | 20220222
> p   | test2@mail.not | 2022-02-22 22:28:22 | 20220222
> h   | test3@mail.not | 2022-02-22 22:22:23 | 20220222
> p   | test4@mail.not | 2022-02-22 22:22:24 | 20220222
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f20d77d550ab1318edb5df4047f88e60)*